# How to start another animation on current position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So this is my box

```
<div class="mybox"></div>
```

And i have a animation

```
.mybox{
  animation:right 5s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  padding:50px;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  display:block;
  background-color:black;
}
@keyframes 

right{from{left:0px;}to{left:300px 
;}}
@keyframes 
left{from{right:0px;}to{right:300p 
 x;}}
```

And i have two button

```
<button onclick="leftFunction">left</button>
<button onclick="rightFunction">right</button>
```

Then if i click left it will go left while it is going left then i click right i want to stop the left animation and go right but the right animation must start on current position and not teleport and go right.

Please help :(
Im new to stack overflow

Here is the js

```
function leftFunction() {
             
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.animation 
= "left 4s";
}
function rightFunction() {
              
 document.getElementById("myDIV").style. 
animation = "right 4s";
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code for `leftFunction` and `rightFunction`

Comment: Done thanks for asking beacause i forgot to add it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a number of issues I found with the code that you posted, but you were on the right track.

1. Your DOM method was looking for an element with an ID of `myDIV` which does not exist, I changed it to `document.querySelector(".mybox")` since that is the class name of your div.
2. You weren't invoking the function call on your `onclick` handler, not sure you were getting anything to happen at all...  Add the `()` invoke it onclick.
3. Your code layout was not following normal spacing conventions, but it is difficult to write code into stack overflow, so I understand. I made the changes I saw necessary.
4. You were setting position values to your div, but there was no `position` property declared.  Position is `static` by default which doesn't respond to `left` or `right`.  I used `relative` as that will keep the div in the document flow.
5. Changing `left` on one animation and `right` on another will maintain the previous left or right values, respectively and could cause your div to shrink or grow unexpectedly.  I changed it to only affect the `left` property.

##### And now for the solution

Change your keyframes to only update the `left` property.  Call the function from onclick and pass in the `event` object.  This will allow you to have just one function to handle the change in animation, and can take the event target's `innerHTML` to set the name of the animation desired.

Make use of CSS custom properties, so that value can be mutated in javascript, and make your `from` properties start at the custom property.  In this case `--cur-pos`.

When the function is called, get the div element, and find it's computed `left` value with `document.getComputedStyle()`, then update the custom property `--cur-pos` with that value.  That way the animation always starts where the div is currently positioned.

Et voila! You should be good to go.  You might have to tweak the starting `--cur-pos` value to have the div start where you want, and also update the `to` values to end where you want, just make sure to choose either `left` or `right` for updating horizontal position, not both.

```js
function changeAnimation(e) {
  const box = document.querySelector(".mybox")
  const pos = window.getComputedStyle(box).left
  box.style.setProperty("--cur-pos", pos)
  box.style.animationName = e.target.innerHTML
}
```

```css
.mybox {
  --cur-pos: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  animation: right 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes right {
  from { left: var(--cur-pos); }
  to { left: 300px; }
}

@keyframes left {
  from { left: var(--cur-pos); }
  to { left: 0px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox"></div>
<button onclick="changeAnimation(event)">left</button>
<button onclick="changeAnimation(event)">right</button>
```

Comment: this helped me alot :) and can i also have top bottom?

Comment: Good, I'm glad it helped.  Don't forget to mark the answer correct so future visitors know what solved the issue, if at all.  I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but if you need additional help, it would be better to create another post so as to keep the current scope of this post focused.  Again, for future visitors.

Comment: Or we could move this discussion to chat.

Comment: sorry  about the chechk because im new to stack overflow rlly sorry :)